# R Plumber API unnest list

Tags: r, plumber

I query one of my plumber APIs via R using

```
resp <- httr::GET("http://myserver/api/get_ids", httr::accept_json(),
                  httr::add_headers(Authorization = Sys.getenv("key")))
nested_data <- httr::content(resp)
```

While this works, I'm not satisfied with the way the returned data looks like. That is, the data returns a tibble as a nested list. However, I want the return to be a single list - not nested. For example, the current output of this requests looks like thos:
nested_data

```
$ids
$ids[[1]]
[1]
$ids[[2]]
[2]
...
```

However, I want an output like this:

```
$ids
1 2 3, ....
```

I know that this can be achieved with  `data <- lapply(nested_data, unlist, use.names=FALSE)`. However, this operation might be time consuming for big lists and does remove NULL values, so there is no guarantee the all list items are of the same length afterwards.

For the plumber call itself, I used the `#* @serializer unboxedJSON` tag.

Any ideas :-)?